# Spread multiple columns [tidyr]

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I would like to spread data over multiple columns using `tidyr`.

```
  dat <- data.frame(ID = rep(1,10), 
  col1 = LETTERS[seq(1,10)], 
  col2 = c(letters[seq(1,8)],NA,NA),
  col3 = c(rep(NA,8),"5",NA),
  col4 = c(rep(NA,8),NA,"value"))
```

The expected outcome is:

```
Out <- data.frame(t(c(1,letters[seq(1,8)],"5","value")),row.names=NULL)
colnames(Out) <- c("ID",LETTERS[seq(1,10)])
```

I came up with:

```
a <- dat %>% gather(variable, value, -(ID:col1)) %>% 
     unite(temp, col1, variable) %>% 
     spread(temp, value)
a[,-which(is.na(a))]
```

which is clumsy and also changes the column names. Is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use the `na.rm=TRUE` in `gather`, remove the 'variable' with `select` and use `spread`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(dat, variable, val, -(ID:col1), na.rm=TRUE) %>% 
                      select(-variable)  %>% 
                      spread(col1, val)
#  ID A B C D E F G H I     J
#1  1 d b b c b b b a 5 value
```

#### Update

With the devel version of `tidyr` (`tidyr_0.8.3.9000`), we can use `pivot_wider` when there are multiple value columns to be considered

```
dat %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col1, values_from = str_c("col", 2:4)) %>% 
  select_if(~ any(!is.na(.)))
# A tibble: 1 x 11
#     ID col2_A col2_B col2_C col2_D col2_E col2_F col2_G col2_H col3_I col4_J
#  <dbl> <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct> 
#1     1 a      b      c      d      e      f      g      h      5      value
```

---

If we are using `reshape2`, similar option is

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(dat, measure = 3:5, na.rm=TRUE),
                      ID~col1, value.var='value')
```